# Find maximum length of path with only 1

Tags: algorithm, recursion, tree

I have a tree consisting of only binary numbers as node data. Now I must find the maximum length of the path which consist only of nodes that has its node value as 1 and path must be continuous i.e it should not contain any zero on its way.

For example, let's consider this tree:

```
root->data = 0;
root->left->data = 1;
root->right->data = 0;
root->left->left->data = 1;
root->left->right->data = 1;
root->left->left->left->data = 1;
root->left->right->left->data = 1;
root->left->right->right->data = 0;
```

The answer of above tree should be 5.
Please refer  to figure in the link given below:

[Click this for more detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KstEZ.png)

How can I do this?

Comment: A simple traverse of the tree (inorder,preorder, whatever) where you only go into nodes with the proper value. During this traverse keep a counter of the depth.

Answer (score 1):

Basic idea:

```
int GetDepthWithCondition(Node node)
{
    if (node.Data == 0)
        return -100000;
    return 1 + Math.Max(GetDepthWithCondition(node.RightSon), 
                        GetDepthWithCondition(node.LeftSon));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example is weird. I don't see how the answer is 5 when your root has a 0, it should be 0. Plus, it should only be 4 since the longest path is along the entire left side if the root is a 1.

Anyways, this is essentially finding the height of a tree while forcing values to be 1. This is a variant on the [diameter of a binary tree](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/diameter-of-a-binary-tree/) which can be implemented by modifying the basic solution like this:

```
public int MaxDiameterWithOnes(Node node)
{
    if (node == null || node.Data == 0)
        return 0;
    return 1 + Math.Max(MaxDiameterWithOnes(node.Left), MaxDiameterWithOnes(node.Right));
}
```

You can modify this using the second method in the link above to be more efficient.

Comment: Please refer to link. I have posted the figure. Its not necessary that longest that path consist only of one subtree. it can include both subtree.

Comment: @R.Edgar In this case, it is a different problem entirely. It should be relatively straightforward with a Depth-first search though.

Comment: Hmm I think it is solvable using dfs. If you can provide solution it will be helpfull

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm may be the following (pseudo code):

```
maxPath tree | treeHasNoChildren = []               
             | data == 0 = []
             | otherwise = 
                 takeSolutionHavingMaxLength (
                   left:maxPath (left tree), 
                   right:maxPath (right tree)
                 )
```